# how to log an integer value with log.d?

Tags: java, android

I am very new to Android and am trying some simple log to get a random background color. I have the code and it returns an integer between 1-256, or so I think. I need to log the value to check if it's OK, but I'm not sure how to log it with Android.. I've been using `System.out.println("stuff")` to log stuff in the past but I believe that's not how you're supposed to do it in Android.

I have my class:

```
public static int backgroundColorRandomize()
```

that returns

```
return randomRGB;
```

and I try to log it like this

```
Log.d(backgroundColorRandomize(), "value = " + randomRGB);
```

but I need to convert the returned value from `backgroundColorRandomize` to a String in order for it to log.

I tried java's `.toString` but I'm not sure I'm using it right.. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: the first parameter when calling the Log.d is to put the tag. which you'll use to filter the log from the LogCat.

Comment: you can use your name or your application name. i.e Log.d("shanling", "value = " + randomRGB);

Comment: thanks for your reply! I am confused though, can my "tag" be anything? Do I have to put the tag on the method somewhere?

Comment: yes, it can be anything, though it is good if you can make it more specific to what you are trying to log. and no need any method, is just a string.

Comment: oh ok so it is just to identify what I am logging I see.. Ok when I put this `Log.d("backgroundColorRandomize", "value = " + randomRGB);' in my code I get 'unreachable statement' error.. Not sure what is going on. I put it in the class, should I be putting it outside the class?

Comment: unreachable statement means that if you run your program, the program will never reach your particular line of code. most probably is because you are calling a return before the Log.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Log.d("MYINT", "value: " + randomRGB);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
private static final String TAG = YourClass.class.getSimpleName();

...

android.util.Log.d(TAG, String.format("value = %d. random color = %d", randomRGB, backgroundColorRandomize()));
```

More info:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html
- https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Logging libraries: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/57

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I can't quite figure out what is supposed to go where "TAG" is when I read the documentation.. Could you elaborate please? Thanks!

Comment: It is a String that is "Used to identify the source of a log message. It usually identifies the class or activity where the log call occurs." Usually it is just the name of your class.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer `String.valueOf(value)`.

```
Log.d(String.valueOf(backgroundColorRandomize()), "value = " + randomRGB);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Log.d(backgroundColorRandomize() + "" /* <-- all you need. */, "value = " + randomRGB);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
Log.d("MYINT", "value: " + randomRGB.toString());
```